# Part of job application page not translated

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, stack-exchange

I was just casually browsing through the site when I encountered the page with job listings SE the company currently has. I saw that [one offering was based out of Germany](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here/815574/sales-executive). I curiously clicked that, and found that the listing was in German, which I guess is great when your trying to hire someone in Germany.

The application form itself was also translated, except the second, optional, part starting at "LinkedIn Profile". The final submission button is then again correctly translated. Also the "Locate me" link under "Standordt" is not translated as [Cindy Meister](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3077495/cindy-meister) pointed out

[image: Printscreen of job offering on https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here/815574/sales-executive that shows an application form partly translated into German]

Comment: FWIW the link `Locate me` in the top part is also not translated. And the translation of the tile is... well... understandable, but not correct.